# Android Application won't show up even though it said it was installed

Tags: android, android-intent, manifest, program-entry-point, launcher

I am trying to install an application on my android phone. It says it is successful but I don't see it on my phone. 
Here is my xml manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.adr"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
      <receiver android:name=".AdrBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.adr.intent.action.SERVICE">
      </action>   
    </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
      <service android:name=".Adr">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.adr.intent.action.SERVICE">
      </action>   
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>>
      </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Edited Code: Now I am getting errors from the logcat. The application shows up but once I click on it says Unfortunately, adr has stopped. I am getting a lot of things in my logcat now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.adr"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
      <activity android:name=".YourActivity" >
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
     </activity>
      <receiver android:name=".AdrBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.adr.intent.action.SERVICE">
      </action>   
    </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
      <service android:name=".Adr">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.adr.intent.action.SERVICE">
      </action>   
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>>
      </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is what i get in the logcat -

```
06-27 16:38:45.814: D/AndroidRuntime(5324): Shutting down VM
06-27 16:38:45.814: W/dalvikvm(5324): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-27 16:38:45.864: E/AndroidRuntime(5324): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 16:38:45.864: E/AndroidRuntime(5324): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.adr/com.adr.YourActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.adr.YourActivity" on path: /data/app/com.adr-1.apk
06-27 16:38:45.864: E/AndroidRuntime(5324):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
06-27 16:38:45.864: E/AndroidRuntime(5324):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-27 16:38:45.864: E/AndroidRuntime(5324):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-27 16:38:45.864: E/AndroidRuntime(5324):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-27 16:38:45.864: E/AndroidRuntime(5324):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-27 16:38:45.864: E/AndroidRuntime(5324):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-27 16:38:45.864: E/AndroidRuntime(5324):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-27 16:38:45.864: E/AndroidRuntime(5324):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 16:38:45.864: E/AndroidRuntime(5324):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-27 16:38:45.864: E/AndroidRuntime(5324):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-27 16:38:45.864: E/AndroidRuntime(5324):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-27 16:38:45.864: E/AndroidRuntime(5324):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-27 16:38:45.864: E/AndroidRuntime(5324): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.adr.YourActivity" on path: /data/app/com.adr-1.apk
06-27 16:38:45.864: E/AndroidRuntime(5324):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
06-27 16:38:45.864: E/AndroidRuntime(5324):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-27 16:38:45.864: E/AndroidRuntime(5324):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-27 16:38:45.864: E/AndroidRuntime(5324):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
06-27 16:38:45.864: E/AndroidRuntime(5324):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
06-27 16:38:45.864: E/AndroidRuntime(5324):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Is there something in Android debugging console (Android Monitor) ?

Comment: On Eclipse it says that it is uploading to the device then it is installing then it says "success!" and then "done!"

Comment: If you are using Eclipse - yes, you can see error console there. I asked for Android monitor, because I'm using NetBeans

Comment: How do I get to the Android monitor?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse it would be better to see it there, if not Android monitor is in your Android install dir/tools/monitor.bat

Comment: Where would I find it in Eclipse?

Comment: I do not use Eclipse and can't tell u exactly. As far as I know it just shows up like a console. It's name should be "Log Cat"

Comment: I found the Log Cat. What part do you want from it? There are a lot of things in it.

Answer (score 1):

You mean your app does not show up in the applications menu? That is because there is no activity in the app, only a receiver and a service. Declaring MAIN and LAUNCHER for a service does not help.

Comment: Yes, it will not show up in the application menu. How do I edit it to have activity?

Comment: If your app has a user interface, you have to implement a subclass of Activity and then add it to the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <activity android:name=".YourActivity" >
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
     </activity>
```

declare this activity after the application , you are not declaring any activity that is why is not showing up the icon. make sure you add your app name, app icon to the activity above.

### to make it clear

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.style.me.Smaller"
             android:largeHeap="true"
         android:configChanges="locale|orientation|keyboard|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </activity>
```

Comment: This got it to work but then it crashed after that. Do you know what would cause that?

Comment: read the logcat and see what cause the crash. and please do accept the answer so it can help others.

Comment: So it was this?  Didn't find class "com.adr.YourActivity" on path: /data/app/com.adr-1.apk. I was somewhat confused on what you meant when I should "add your app name, app icon to the activity above"

Comment: YourActivity it means your class which contains the main layout of your application. lets say if you created the project from android then the main class will be . com.adr.MainActivity

Comment: Okay, so what would I have to change for that to go away?

Comment: what is your main class ? ? your activity class ? ? the class that first created that holds your layouts, activities etc ? this is the class that suppose to be place in your manifest.

Comment: I am not sure. I am trying to test this out to see if it works. http://sourceforge.net/projects/adaptivedr/ so I think it would be AdrInterface

Comment: this project doesn't have layout (user interface)  neither custom view class. therefore it won't open. unless if you implement your own UI.